# Profiling the GPU of a tablet

Tags: android, unity, mobile, gpu, profiler

We are working on a tablet game in Unity Pro (for the first time). Unity's profiler works great for probing the CPU, but the tablet's GPU isn't supported in the profiler, so we have no idea where the rendering bottlenecks are.

Are there any other means of profiling the GPU of an android tablet? (We are working with a [Samsung galaxy tab 2 10.1](http://www.samsung.com/global/microsite/galaxytab2/10.1/spec.html?type=find) ) How do other mobile devs do this?

We are basically looking for any ways of getting info from the gpu as we're running the game. Benchmarking software wouldn't help; we don't need benchmark scores.

Cheers!

Comment: I don't have a real answer, but maybe try to see if this extensions or one of the references ones is available: http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/EXT/EXT_disjoint_timer_query.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of our team mates found Imagination: http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/powervr_presentations/profiling_tools_android.asp

It is a set of profiling tools for Andorid. You can configure this to your tablet and profile the GPU.

Would be better if Unity supported this on its own, but still, this gets the job done thoroughly.